# Automatically restart Shiny apps after server reboot

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, app-startup

I have a Shiny application that needs to load into memory some fairly large data sets. To save the users some time when browsing to the dashboard, I set the `app_idle_timeout` to zero (using the community version of the Shiny server application), as suggested in the [docs](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts). This works as expected.

However, the underlying data needs to be refreshed daily. Hence, what I would like to do is setting up a cron job that reboots the shiny server (or stops the relevant sessions) every day at 3am and then automatically initiates a new R session so that the data in the global.R is loaded into memory and the dashboard ready to consume instantly.

What I do not understand is how to initiate a particular Shiny application from terminal, i.e. mimic what happens when browsing to the URL of this app on the Shiny server.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The app should start as soon as someone connects to it, you should probably user cron jobs to do a job on the datasets and save it in the directory of the app or insert it back into a database

Comment: I already have a cron job that grabs raw data and aggregates it to the minimum level of granularity needed for the Shiny app. This data then is loaded in global.R. What I need is a way to make the first initialization so that the global.R is loaded and other users can connect to the app without the need to re-load session data.